# Unable to get access token with authorisation code

Tags: php, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

I am getting authorization code after given permission to access my google account. 
But, the below code

```
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
```

throws below error:

> 500 internal server error.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("meme");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType("offline");

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I am getting the authorization code inside `isset` condition. Previously, the same code was working. But, in `oauth 2` it was not working.

Comment: Do I want to know why you are bothering with Oauth2 for the Metadata API which is a public API?

Comment: If you see on the site developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/… of **Acquiring and using an API key** section point No.2 it describes our application need to send an OAuth2.0 token. Can you give a sample working php code to get analytics data.